# Two objects are not contacting with each other, but contactTestBetween() returns a result

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a SceneKit scene and I'm trying to detect when two objects are contacting with each other. I have 2 objects that are closely positioned to each other, but they are not in contact. When I do a contact test for these objects the function contactTestBetween() returns a contact point. Why is this happening?

First, I placed the objects farther from each other. If I place the objects a certain distance from each other contactTestBetween() does not return a value. It seems like there's a magic number.

Second, I did the same test for collision detection between these two objects. Similarly if objects are placed below a certain distance from each other they start moving. What makes this more interesting is the distance limit for the collision detection is lower compared to the distance limit for the contact test.

```
scnView.debugOptions = .showPhysicsShapes
```

This is on, so I can see the how big are the physics shapes.

```
box!.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic,
                                 shape: SCNPhysicsShape(
                              geometry: box!.geometry!,
                               options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: 
                                            SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.boundingBox]))

box2!.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic,
                                  shape: SCNPhysicsShape(
                               geometry: box2!.geometry!,
                                options: [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: 
                                             SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.boundingBox]))

box!.physicsBody!.isAffectedByGravity = false
box2!.physicsBody!.isAffectedByGravity = false

box!.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 2
box2!.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 4

box!.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 4
box2!.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 2
```

Above is the code I use to create physics bodies for the objects.

```
let contactResult = scnView.scene?.physicsWorld.contactTestBetween(box!.physicsBody!, box2!.physicsBody!)
```

That's how I do the contact test between the objects.

Here's a screenshot from the simulator:

[image]

I don't understand why this happening. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are the object moving? I suspect that contact detection is a approximation of "real" contact (remember that there exists `usePreciseCollisionDetection` to enhance this - not sure it will helps here) thus producing some secondary effects in some way...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what documentation says about `contactTestBetween(_:_:options:)` instance method:

> SceneKit sends messages to the physics world’s contactDelegate object only when collisions occur between bodies **whose** `collisionBitMask` and `categoryBitMask` **properties overlap**, and only for collisions **between certain types of bodies**. (For details, see [SCNPhysicsBodyType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbodytype).) Use this method to directly test for contacts between any two bodies at a time of your choosing. For example, to implement a game where the player character can pick up an item, you might call this method when the player presses the “pick up” button to see if the player character is in contact with the item to be picked up.

**But your `.categoryBitMask` and `.contactTestBitMask` are different for these two objects**.

And what both [.collisionBitMask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514772-collisionbitmask) are?

And one more thing:

> For nodes containing ***custom geometry***, the physics shape SceneKit automatically creates is a rough approximation of the geometry. This approximation, or `convex hull`, **provides a compromise between accuracy and performance in collision detection**.
>
> For the best collision detection performance, create an SCNPhysicsShape instance based on a basic geometry class (`SCNBox`, `SCNSphere`, `SCNPyramid`, `SCNCone`, `SCNCylinder`, or `SCNCapsule`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesn't answer my question. I believe Jean is correct.